# Given $A: R^n \rightarrow R^m$ a linear operator, show that exist $x \in R^n$ such that $|x|{n}=1 $ and $|A(x)|{m}= | |A| | $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-transformations

Given $A: R^n \rightarrow  R^m$ a linear operator, show that exist $x \in R^n$ such that $|x|{n}=1 $ and $|A(x)|{m}= | |A| |  $

We define $||A||=sup \lbrace |A(x)| : |x| \leq 1 \rbrace$

I try this

$\lbrace x \in R^n : |x|=1 \rbrace $ is a compact subset

Therefore sup and inf can be reached
So there exists x such that $|x|=1$

but im stuck from here

Comment: Consider the function $f \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = |A(x)|$. Then $f$ is continuous, and since $D^n := \{x \in \Bbb R^n : |x| \leq 1\}$ is compact, it follows that the supremum and the infimum of $f(D^n)$ can be reached. Do you know what that means?

Comment: @azif00 so I can take $x_{max} \in D^n$ such that $f(x_{max})=sup \lbrace f(x) : x \in D^n \rbrace = sup \lbrace |A(x)| : x \in D^n \rbrace $ so then $||A||=|A(x)|$ right?

Comment: $\|A\| = |A(x_\max)|$, yes.